# Finding Q factor of Spring

Tags: harmonic-oscillator

I am trying to find the Q factor of a spring when damped (comparing with different mediums of different viscosity). I have a exponential decay graph (absolute value of peaks of the oscillation VS time). Is it possible to obtain the Q factor from my graph or some coefficient that makes physical sense? The constants I have are mass and k (spring constant)

Since this is an exponential decay graph, I have a feeling I can do something with logs to the graph, but does the exponent that I find after applying log mean anything of physical value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is approximately half the damping constant $\beta$ (in the ODE $\ddot x+\beta\dot x+\omega^2 x=0$). The approximation is quite good if $\beta \ll \omega$.

Comment: Is it because the exponent = k/2m and k is the damping coefficient shown in the equation F=-kv? (k being beta in your answer)

Comment: @선풍기 No, $k$ is not $\beta$ in my answer. $k=m\beta$.

Comment: Ah thanks for the correction. Although I'm not so confident with differential equations, I marked it as an answer for other people.